# Convert JSON to CSV with complex arrays in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have several JSON files with nested data. Utilizing Python, I was able to use `pandas` to help with that:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json (r'data.json')
export_csv = df.to_csv (r'data.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

However, this only works for simple JSON files. The ones I have are complex with nested arrays and some of the JSON data is merged under the columns. For example, if we're going to use this sample data:

#### `data.json`

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": {
      "english": "Bulbasaur",
      "french": "Bulbizarre"
    },
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 45,
      "Attack": 49,
      "Defense": 49
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": {
      "english": "Ivysaur",
      "french": "Herbizarre"
    },
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 60,
      "Attack": 62,
      "Defense": 63
    }
  }
]
```

The result ends up like the following:

[image: CSV Output]

You can see that any array past the first level is showing it in JSON (e.g. `{'english': 'Bulbasaur', 'french': 'Bulbizarre'}`). Ideally, it should break those child arrays into a column with the name of the element:

[image: Expected Output]

On top of that, the other JSON files have different element names and order. Therefore, the script should *catch all* of the different element names and then convert them into CSV columns.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How standard are these columns? Do you know its always, say, "name.french" and "name.engilsh" or might any manner of name types show up over time? That would mean adding columns dynamically and having pre-existing rows put NONE into those cells.

Comment: @tdelaney: Unfortunately, not all of them have the same element names or order. So this would check all of the element names in the JSON and turn them into columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out flatten_json

```
from flatten_json import flatten
dic = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": {
      "english": "Bulbasaur",
      "french": "Bulbizarre"
    },
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 45,
      "Attack": 49,
      "Defense": 49
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": {
      "english": "Ivysaur",
      "french": "Herbizarre"
    },
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 60,
      "Attack": 62,
      "Defense": 63
    }
  }
]

dic_flattened = (flatten(d, '.') for d in dic)
df = pd.DataFrame(dic_flattened)
```

Output:

```
   id name.english name.french type.0  type.1  base.HP  base.Attack  base.Defense
0   1    Bulbasaur  Bulbizarre  Grass  Poison       45           49            49
1   2      Ivysaur  Herbizarre  Grass  Poison       60           62            63
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) will get you almost there but to split the list you need something extra:

```
f = lambda x: 'type.{}'.format(x + 1)
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('type').values.tolist()).rename(columns=f))

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   id name.english name.french  ...  base.Defense  type.1  type.2
0   1    Bulbasaur  Bulbizarre  ...            49   Grass  Poison
1   2      Ivysaur  Herbizarre  ...            63   Grass  Poison

[2 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like you a specifying the `type` element to split up. I should of clarified that not all of the JSON files have the same element names or order. So it needs to *catch all* of the element names in the JSON file and then convert them to CSV columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest using a for loop, coupled with a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), usually easier and faster when doing iterations (that do not have aggregations) to stay out of pandas until the final output:

```
from collections import defaultdict

df = defaultdict(list)

val = {}
box = []
for entry in data: # data is the sample data you shared
    for key, value in entry.items():
        if key == "id":
            temp = [(key, value)]
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            temp = [(f"{key}.{k}", v) for k, v in value.items()]
        else:
            temp = [(f"{key}.{k}", v) for k, v in enumerate(value, 1)]
        box.extend(temp)

for k, v in box:
    df[k].append(v)


df

defaultdict(list,
            {'id': [1, 2],
             'name.english': ['Bulbasaur', 'Ivysaur'],
             'name.french': ['Bulbizarre', 'Herbizarre'],
             'type.1': ['Grass', 'Grass'],
             'type.2': ['Poison', 'Poison'],
             'base.HP': [45, 60],
             'base.Attack': [49, 62],
             'base.Defense': [49, 63]})
```

Create dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(df)

    id  name.english    name.french type.1  type.2  base.HP base.Attack base.Defense
0   1   Bulbasaur      Bulbizarre   Grass   Poison     45      49       49
1   2   Ivysaur        Herbizarre   Grass   Poison     60      62       63
```

Comment: Thanks for the new approach. From your code, it looks like the field name are predefined in `defaultdict` at the bottom? I should of clarified that the other JSON files have different elements names and order. So I would like this to catch all of the possible element names out there and then convert it to a CSV. Updated my question to clarify.

Comment: _"it looks like the field name are predefined in defaultdict at the bottom?"_ I don't think that's a pre-definition, I think that's the output of the program if you print `df`. You should not include that part in your script. It wouldn't make much sense to have a predefinition at the end of your program, in any case.